# Word macro for 'movie typing'

Tags: vb.net, ms-word

You know in movies they show the actor 'typing' (randomly mashing at the keyboard) and then on the screen a stream of text appears in Word. I want to create a macro that achieves this - so it's basic keyboard capture and then display of a provided word file, a bit at a time.

Any pointers in the right direction please! Total newb to VB programming, but I did my degree in Computer science a few years back - just very rusty through lack of use!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the namespace 'System.Windows.Forms' you can use the class 'SendKeys'
Example

```
SendKeys.Send("What the actor types?")
```

You can read more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send.aspx)
Please notice that the keys are being send to the foreground window on windows.

To change the foreground window you can simply use the function

```
Public Declare Function SetForegroundWindow Lib "User32.dll" (ByVal window As IntPtr) As Boolean
```

**Please notice:**
After you invoke the function "Send" the computer begins to type directly. If you want the computer to delay, for example 2 seconds you can use the following function

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2 * 1000)
```